# How to do simple es6 module loading in a browser?

Tags: javascript, browser, module

I'm trying to use the feature of new browsers that allows you to load JavaScript modules as apposed to scripts.

Every example of this seems super straight forward. You simply change the type attribute from `"text/javascript"` to `"module"`.

I have a simple test.js file that just grabs a DOM node and sets its inner HTML to "Hello" :

```
const output = document.querySelector("#output");
output.innerHTML = "hello";
```

This works when `type = "text/javascript"` but fails with `type = "module"` :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JS Modules</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <h1>JS Modules</h1>
      <div id="output"></div>
    </main>
    <script type="module" src="./test.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="module"></script>
```

is only supported in modern browsers.They're in…

1. Safari 10.1.
2. Chrome 61.
3. Firefox 54 – behind the
   dom.moduleScripts.enabled setting in about:config.
4. Edge 16.

other browsers than that, your script won't load

For backwards compatibility, you can add the `nomodule` script

```
<script type="module" src="./test.js"></script>
<script nomodule src="fallback.js"></script>
```

here's a more complete reference
https://jakearchibald.com/2017/es-modules-in-browsers/